# Google Now API that would allow implementing a client app

Tags: web-services, api, google-now

Is there something like Google Now API that would allow obtaining a list of cards for a given Google account via for example a Web Service? I would like to implement my own app/widget that would present current cards from Google Now.

Answer (score 1):

Currently Google Now integration is only possible by using [Google Schemas](https://developers.google.com/schemas/now/cards) for event, flight, hotel and restaurant reservations. You have to add special markup to emails which then gets evaluated by Gmail.

For the near future Google [announced](http://thenextweb.com/google/2015/03/14/a-google-now-open-api-is-in-the-works-and-support-for-theme-park-ride-queue-times/) an open API for Google Now, which is currently in a [pilot program](http://www.google.com/landing/now/integrations.html) with about 100 apps.